# membership provider usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have my Membership provider. My application consists of several projects - UI,DAL,Services,BusinessLogic. If I use Membership.GetUser() function in UI project then I get instance of currently logged in user. If I write the same code in Service project, I get null. Can anybody suggest me possible problem?

Comment: Are you calling the service layer from your UI?

Comment: yes, but I don't want to pass UserId for each method where I use it in service project

Answer (score 0):

I always depend on `Membership.GetUser(username)` because have experienced `.GetUser()` returning `null` too. I'll assume you have your Service layer reference `System.Web` namespace, otherwise you have to do now.

My answer does not tell you why this is happening but I hope you could have the alternative. Instead of using `Membership.GetUser()` which works in the UI (.aspx), use this instead

```
string currentUsername = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(currentUsername);
```

I believe this should work.

Comment: I get errror that `HttpContext.Current` is null. It's likely I have not properly implemented something but I can't figure out what

Comment: It is better if you passed the username to your service layer which would prevent it from being dependent on the Web layer. Also, did you add reference to System.Web and import the namespace?

Comment: Null HttpContext: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/can-httpcontext-current-null-t3561352.html